# ckeditor5 create element "image" with attributes

Tags: ckeditor5

I'm trying to create a custom plugin to insert an image from my already built media browser. I'd like to attach some attributes to the image. No matter what I try it only inserts the image with the `src` and `alt` attribute. In other words my image is always missing the `data-source` and `class` attribute. I've tried the data attribute key as `dataSource` but that also doesn't work.

```
const imageElement = writer.createElement( 'image',  {
    'src': src,
    'alt': alt,
    'data-sources': dataSources,
    'class': cls
} );
editor.model.insertContent( imageElement, editor.model.document.selection );
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where in the docs is the schema for all the elements even defined? Can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make 2 things to process new attributes of an image.

First, you need to extend [the schema](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/schema.html) with proper rules which inform model that given attributes are allowed in the editor.

Second thing is to inform the editor how to [convert](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/architecture/editing-engine.html#conversion) given attribute to model structure and vice-versa with proper converters.

Unfortunately, image converters are quite complicated, because the image is always wrapped with `<figure>`. Below you can find code and link to working sample how you can create such converters (converters are created based on the [source code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/blob/2c588e3a52bf244b269740071eb1d19d013d0c64/src/image/converters.js#L113-L133) of the image plugin for CKEditor5). For the purpose of this sample, the `data-source` attribute is stored in the model as `dSource` attribute of an image element.

```
editor.model.schema.extend( 'image', { allowAttributes: 'dSource' } );

editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).attributeToAttribute( {
    view: 'data-source',
    model: 'dSource'
} );

editor.conversion.for( 'downcast' ).add( dispatcher => {
    dispatcher.on( 'attribute:dSource:image', ( evt, data, conversionApi ) => {
        if ( !conversionApi.consumable.consume( data.item, evt.name ) ) {
            return;
        }

        const viewWriter = conversionApi.writer;
        const figure = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement( data.item );
        const img = figure.getChild( 0 );

        if ( data.attributeNewValue !== null ) {
            viewWriter.setAttribute( 'data-source', data.attributeNewValue, img );
        } else {
            viewWriter.removeAttribute( 'data-source', img );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Link to working sample: https://codepen.io/msamsel/pen/pXKRed?editors=1010